# how to declare a public string with a textbox's text

Tags: c#, winforms, string, textbox

i am trying to do

```
      public string str = txtText.Text;
```

but it wont let me use txtText.txt so how would I declare that so it can be used everywhere?

I can't use it in the button1_click event because if I do it messes it up because I am having a string retrieve from the textbox and set to the textbox so it doesn't work right so I have to have it retrieve the textbox's text somewhere else then set to it.

Comment: What do you want to do? (also, using a period every now and then helps people understand what you write better).

Comment: just define a string outside click event like public string str; and inside click event populate this like str = txtText.Text.

Comment: make your textbox access modifier to public or internal.

Comment: @daryal i tried that but it still does it because it still retrieves from the textbox and sets to the textbox

Comment: More code.  Where are you trying to declare this?  What click handler?  You have to show us the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your declaration to this (I **guess** you're trying to make public your TextBox Text property):

```
public string TextBoxText
{
   get { return txtText.Text; }
   set { txtText.Text = value; }
}
```

If you simply want to get that value inside your event handler (and inside the same class where your TextBox is declared) then you don't have to use the public specifier in the declaration:

```
string str = txtText.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string str;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            str=txtText.Text;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static class
and then set your textbox text to it

```
public static class GlobalClass
{
    public string PropertyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


private void txtText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalClass.PropertyName=txtText.Text
}
```

give that in textchange event